# Wrapping a model around a rigged model

Tags: mesh, rigging

I have a rigged foot model. I want to wrap a shoe model (unrigged) around the foot model.

How can I do so while also making the shoe model follow the foot rig. For example, when the toes bend, the shoe bends the same way.

Comment: Shrinkwrap?....

Comment: create the shoe mesh in front and side views so that it follows the foot profile, then rig it to the same bones as the foot